# Erro: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:NO) ao aceder a Website

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, lamp

Boas tardes,

Tenho estado a tentar correr um Website através de um raspberry para aceder com acesso remoto. Instalei o OS Pipplware, juntamente com o Lamp e phpmyadmin. Enviei através do filezilla a basedados do website e correu tudo perfeição. O phpmyadmin aparecia com erros, o que me impedia a importação da base de dados para lá, mas depois de uma reconfiguração consegui por tudo a funcionar. No entanto o Website, ainda apresenta o mesmo erro:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:NO)

E ao tentar resolver, reparei que no mysql, tanto no user

```
mysql -h localhost -u user -p database_name
```

como no root,

```
mysql -u localhost -u root -p database_name
```

Continua a aparecer o mesmo erro 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:NO)
Alguém conhece este erro ou sabe como resolver? Agradeço toda a ajuda que oferecerem.

Comment: Experimente reiniciar o MySQL como mysqld_safe. Além disso, dê um flush nas permissões.

Comment: tenta usar o sudo antes de iniciar o mysql

Answer (score 22):

1 - Instale o MySQL e inicie o serviço com o comando abaixo:

```
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

2 - Configure o MySQL inicialmente com o comando abaixo:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

3 - Logue no MySQL com o comando abaixo:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

4 - Agora, digite o comando abaixo substituindo a palavra **password** pela senha que desejar:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'; flush privileges;
```

Pronto, você já deve estar acessando o MySQL sem problemas.

Answer (score 4):

Tenta isso para o erro mysql access denied

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

ou

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

proxima etapa:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

se pegar erro tenta esse:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

dai segue:

```
mysql

mysql>UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root' and host='localhost';
```

Se voce for querer NO PAss:

```
mysql>UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('') WHERE User='root' and host='localhost';
```

se aparecer este erro 'your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements root', entao:

```
mysql>uninstall plugin validate_password;
```

ou

```
mysql>SET GLOBAL validate_password_policy=LOW;
```

Entao tente novamente:

```
mysql>UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('') WHERE User='root' and host='localhost'
```

Atualize os previlegios:

```
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql>exit
```

Da um Restart no serviço:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Comment: Ajudou muito! Obrigado

Comment: pra mim so com o restart ja resolveu

Answer (score 2):

Esse erro indica que você está tentando acessar a base de dados pelo usuário root sem informar a senha....

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:NO)
```

Verifique no seu banco de dados qual a senha desse usuário e depois tente:

```
mysql -u localhost -u root -psenha database_name
```

a senha deve estar "colada" no -p

Answer (score -1):

Edite o usuário  de acesso ao MySQL, no meu caso eu mudei os privilégios dele de "%"(qualquer banco) para "localhost", pronto funcionou.

Como o seu esta online deve ser o inverso eu acho,quem estiver tendo o mesmo erro mete o dedo ai, aqui deu certo, boa sorte.